# Error counting the quantity of items in a json in java with Rest Assured

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

When I call the https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories url Json carries 16 categories, but the counter is showing 50 categories.
I didn't quite understand where the error is.

Api: https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories

```
JsonPath QuantidadeCategorias = new JsonPath(response.asString());
System.out.println("Quantidade de Cateorias: " + QuantidadeCategorias.toString().length());
```

**Quantidade de Categorias: 50**

```
[
    "animal",
    "career",
    "celebrity",
    "dev",
    "explicit",
    "fashion",
    "food",
    "history",
    "money",
    "movie",
    "music",
    "political",
    "religion",
    "science",
    "sport",
    "travel"
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error. the length() method returns the length of a given string.

If you want to count the categories, which is a list you need to store the answer as a list and check the size() of the list.

This will give the number of categories (i.e 16 )

```
List < String > jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
System.out.println(jsonResponse.size());
```